# Is there a simple way to conduct the this transformation on a multi-indexed dataframe?

Tags: pivot, transform, reshape, multi-index

Please see the attached image showing a DataFrame (left_table in the picture, wrote this as a code in the following). I want to transform it to the right_table in a simple way (using pivot, melt, transposing etc).

```
 arrays = [
    ["T1", "T1", "T2", "T2"],
    ["C2", "C3", "C2", "C3"],
            ]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["C1", "second"])
index

Left_table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4), index=["N1", "N2"], columns=index)

Left_table
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
Left_table = (
    Left_table.stack(0)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "C1", "C1": "T"})
)


Left_table.columns.name = None
Left_table = Left_table.sort_values(by=["T", "C1"])

print(Left_table.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| C1 | T | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | T1 | 1.10134 | 0.52524 |
| N2 | T1 | 1.45332 | 0.226281 |
| N1 | T2 | 0.816961 | -0.677362 |
| N2 | T2 | 1.00841 | 0.0634249 |